# How can I evaluate the following bivariate distribution?

Tags: probability, joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, convolution

Say $A$ and $B$ and $C$ and $D$ are four random variables, such that $A\not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp B$ and $C\not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp D$. How can I evaluate a bivariate CDF of the form?
\begin{equation}
P(A+B<0,C+D<0)
\end{equation}

Comment: Could you provide specific information about the distributions?  If not, your question reduces to the general one about $\Pr(X\lt 0,\ Y\lt 0)$ with nothing at all assumed about $X=A+B$ and $Y=C+D,$ leaving little to be said.

Comment: @whuber Sorry yes the question is awfully vague. Say $A\sim N(0,1)$ and $C\sim N(0,1)$, where $A\perp\!\!\!\perp C$, and $B$ and $D$ are each distributed as $N(0,1/1-\rho^2)$ and $B\not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp D$. Thanks

Comment: There's a subtlety: to make progress you need to stipulate the joint distribution of $(A,B,C,D).$  The fact each is separately Normal does not imply they are jointly Normal.  If you assume joint Normality, then you can find your question answered in several threads here on CV, because then $(X=A+B, Y=C+D)$ has an easily computable Bivariate Normal distribution and your probability is seen to be associated with a single quadrant, resulting in a simple formula.